# Batch assign textures with same name as materials?

Tags: python, texturing, materials

So I have this blend file with over 50+ materials named NDS_Material.001, NDS_Material.002... and so on. I wanted to assign a texture, which happen to share the same name as the material in question, to each individual material? Is there a way to assign them en masse without having to go through every single material?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Yes it's possible. It depends a bit on how your materials are defined. Can you share a screenshot of the node setup ? I assume they're all very similar.

Comment: with a python script - for sure